# Javascript Unit test DOM elements

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom

I just started building unit tests (using QUnit) for my javascript and I have a function which takes a div and manipulates its children.

How can I create a test for this?

I was thinking of creating a document fragment with the expected DOM tree in each case and test against it. But since the parents etc are different, wouldn't a recursive check fail? How else can I do this test?

Answer (score 1):

Have a DOM reset function that you can call after every test to get back into a neutral state.

Run your function that manipulates the DOM.

Then manually check the DOM is in the correct state by going through it and just asserting everything is where it should be.

Rather recursively comparing it with a DOMFragment loop through the DOM and check that your function has created the new elements, changed classes, changed text, changed attributes, etc.

After you've written a few tests, wrap things in functions and DRY your code out.

Writing code like this means you will probably duplicate a lot of code in your unit tests where your checking very similar things in the DOM. To make it nicer to re-use these take common pieces of code and place them in functions.

Comment: Cleaning up the DOM is not an issue as the modifications are localised (trackable). "manually check the DOM" ? Could you explain that? How do I assert whether everything is where it should be?

Could you also explain "DRY your code out"?

Comment: @Diff.Thinkr hope that clarifies it

Comment: In fact, the DOM manipulations and other changes such as those to className etc are made by separate functions that are called by the function in question. Even if I verify that the the separate functions work perfectly, how would I assert that the logic and the resulting modified DOM is as expected programatically? For eg, if I'm expecting 3 nodes to be appended to a Span but due to logic error only 2 are appended, verifying the basic appending function will not show this fault.

Comment: @DiffThinkr you call the function that manipulates the span, you then `assert(span.childNodes.length === 3)`

Comment: qUnit supports using a [#qunit-fixture](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#keeping-tests-atomic) container and all contents are automatically reset on start of a new test.

Answer (score 0):

I found a node.[isEqualNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-isEqualNode)() function that seems to do the required work. It doesn't seem to compare attributes. I want classNames,ids and data-* attributes also to be compared.